# How to find depth and score of unfetched URLS in Nutch

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

Hi I had crawled a website using nutch 1.5.1 with following parameters. -depth=20 and -topN=800. Now I have a fairly large number of URLS (approx 6K) that are with status db_unfetched. I want to identify 2 things:

1. Why is their status unfetched. Is there some way to trace the reason why a URL was ignored while crawling. I checked the URL filters (they are all in place).
2. Can I find out at what depth each URL was discovered by Nutch. Are all the unfetched pages (all these pages have content so no 404 error) found at depth of 20 or some pages were ignored even before it reached that depth.

I cannot afford to crawl that website again, Are there any commands that I can use to traceback scoring of URLS and identifying their depths.

Comment: When Nutch ignoring a URL it prints out something did you check them?

Comment: No I dint see if there were any ignored URLS in the log. And I resolved the issue, it was being caused by topK, it should have a sufficiently large value, otherwise a lot of pages at each depth are missed.

Comment: @user2204324 If you solved your own issue you can add it as an answer and mark it as such. You won't earn any reputation on it, but it is the right thing to do.

Comment: Well there is still no solution as to how one can trace at which depth was the url discovered and ignored. I will, however for ur convenience mark it resolved!